# Scala : transform a list into a map

Tags: list, scala, dictionary, functional-programming

I have an animal class defined as

```
case class Animal(name: String, properties: List[String])
```

Given a list of Animals, I want a map from property -> list of animals that satisfy that property

As an example, if I have input as, say,

```
List(
    Animal("Dog", 
           List("has tail",
                "can swim",
                "can bark",
                "can bite")),
    Animal("Tuna", 
           List("can swim",
                "has scales", 
                "is edible")),
    Animal("Black Mamba",
           List("has scales",
                "is venomous",
                "can bite"))
)
```

The output should be

```
Map(
  "has tail" -> List(Dog)
  "can swim" -> List(Tuna,Dog)
  "can bark" -> List(Dog)
  "has scales" -> List(Tuna,Snake)
  "is edible" -> List(Tuna)
  "is venomous" -> List(Snake)
  "can bite" -> List(Dog,Snake)
)
```

I am pretty new to functional programming. I can do this in an imperative manner, but have been struggling to come up with a functional solution to it. Any pointers are most welcome! :)

Comment: Did you try out the function groupBy of ImmutableList? This looks to be the thing you are looking for.

Comment: This just has to be an assignment.

Comment: @Paul Nope. It's a reddit dailyprogrammer challenge :))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to get a list of key-value pairs to start.  We can start this problem by first seeing how we would covert a single `Animal` to a list of key-value pairs.  You may have heard of the `map` function.  That allows you to transform lists and other basic structures by applying a function to each element in the list.  We can use it to good effect here:

```
animal.properties.map(property => (property, animal.name))
```

Here we're taking an animal's `properties`, and for each out, apply the anonymous function: `property => (property, animal.name)`.  This function creates a tuple (key-value pair in this case) of the property together with the animal's name.

Now we want to apply this to all the animals in the the list.  That may sound like another `map`, but then we would have a list of lists of tuples, when really we just want a list of tuples.  That's when you use `flatMap` which takes in a method that returns a list and applies it to each element, and flattens the list.  So we just apply the above method to each element.

```
val kvps = animals.flatMap(animal => animal.properties.map(property => (property, animal.name))).toMap
```

Now we have a list of key-value pairs.  Now we want to group them by their key.  The `groupBy` method will return a list of tuples, where the left side is a key and the right side is a list of key-value pairs.  This is almost what we want, but we just want the values on the right side.  So we can do:

```
kvps.groupBy { case (key, value) => key }.toMap.mapValues(keyValues => keyValues.map { case (key, value) => value })
```

Altogether it might look like:

```
animals.flatMap { animal =>
    animal.properties map { property => (animal, property) }
}.groupBy { case (key, value) => key }.toMap mapValues { keyValues =>
    keyValues map { case (key, value) => value }
}
```

Of course, Scala has tons of syntactic sugar that can make this method very terse:

```
animals.flatMap(a => a.properties.map(_ -> a.name)).groupBy(_._1).toMap.mapValues(_.map(_._2))
```

Comment: Accepted your answer since you provided a detailed explanation of all the steps along the way to arrive at the final one liner. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

One such way would be as follows

```
animals.
  flatMap(a => a.properties.map(p => (p, a.name)))
  .groupBy(_._1)
  .mapValues(_.map(_._2))
```

The `flatMap` gives you a List of Tuples of Property -> Animal Name

The `groupBy` then groups by Property name, yielding a `Map[String, List[(String,String)]` where the key of the `Map` is the Property and the value is a Tuple of Property Name -> Animal Name

The `mapValues` then takes the resulting `List((String,String))` of map values and converts that to just the second part of the Tuple which is the name of the animal

Answer (score 1):

```
case class Animal(name: String, properties: List[String])

val animals = List(
  Animal("Dog", List("has tail","can swim","can bark","can bite")),
  Animal("Tuna", List("can swim", "has scales", "is edible")), 
  Animal("Black Mamba", List("has scales", "is venomous", "can bite"))
)


animals
 .flatMap(a => a.properties.map(ab => ab -> a.name))
 .groupBy(_._1)
 .map(g => g._1 -> g._2.map(_._2)).toMap
```

The approach is following

- Create tuples (property -> animalNames)
- Group by property
- Map tuple (property, List((property, name))) to (property, List(name))

Comment: Can you please put a transformation per line for better readability? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In Scala 2.13, you could use `groupMapReduces`

```scala
Welcome to Scala 2.13.2 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_181).
Type in expressions for evaluation. Or try :help.

scala> :pa
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

case class Animal(name: String, properties: List[String])

val animals = List(
  Animal("Dog", List("has tail","can swim","can bark","can bite")),
  Animal("Tuna", List("can swim", "has scales", "is edible")),
  Animal("Black Mamba", List("has scales", "is venomous", "can bite"))
)


(for {
  animal <- animals
  property <- animal.properties
} yield Seq(property, animal.name)).groupMapReduce(_.head)(x => List(x.last))(_ ++ _)



// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

class Animal

val animals: List[Animal] = List(Animal(Dog,List(has tail, can swim, can bark, can bite)), Animal(Tuna,List(can swim, has scales, is edible)), Animal(Black Mamba,List(has scales, is venomous, can bite)))

val res0: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,List[String]] = 
HashMap(
is venomous -> List(Black Mamba), 
is edible -> List(Tuna), 
can swim -> List(Dog, Tuna), 
can bite -> List(Dog, Black Mamba), 
can bark -> List(Dog), 
has scales -> List(Tuna, Black Mamba),
has tail -> List(Dog))
```

The convert code is

```scala
(for {
  animal <- animals
  property <- animal.properties
} yield Seq(property, animal.name)).groupMapReduce(_.head)(x => List(x.last))(_ ++ _)
```

Then, let me explain it line by line.

We have input data, like a collection of `key -> List(value)` and we want to convert it to something like a collection of `value -> List(key)`

First, we need to flatten it to `(value, key)` pairs. That's what `for` expression does.

```scala
for {
  animal <- animals
  property <- animal.properties
} yield Seq(property, animal.name)
```

It will return something like  `List(List(has tail, Dog), List(can swim, Dog), ...`

Then we should group the result by `property` and reduce the grouped value to a `List`, that's what `groupMapReduce` does.

- In first part, we group result by `_.head`, that's to say `property` of animal
- In second part, we map grouped value to `name` of animal by `x => List(x, last)`, here `x` is `Seq(property, animal.name)`, it only contains two elements, so the last one is `name`
- In third part, we contact all the `List` of animal name. So we get the final result.